# RTL8723DE Driver install in kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, realtek

Am new to kali linux and my hp laptop is not detecting any wifi network.
here is the rsult for lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
```

i Guess i need to install RLT8723DE wifi driver.
I even tried that by

```
cd Downloads/
git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
```

later when i gave "make" command i got this

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

From where i refered i got another way too so i tried that

```
sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
```

Then i got this result

```
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/..-rtlwifi_new does not exist.
```

Source https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/how-to-install-drivers-wifi-RTL8723DE-for-kali-linux/td-p/6641223

Please can anyone help me fix this.

---

I tried what u said sir @GAD3R but am getting new error.

```
aashiq@kali:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/aashiq/Downloads/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:79: all] Error 2
```

And also i checked by going in that path `/lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/`
And there is no directory called `build`

Answer (score 0):

See the  [installation instruction](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88)  in the LWFinger repository.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtw_8723de
sudo modprobe -v rtw_8723de
```

Comment: Ok will check on it

Comment: I tried what u said sir @GAD3R but am getting new error.
`aashiq@kali:~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/aashiq/Downloads/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:79: all] Error 2`